# Simple bash script: use of and operator

Tags: bash

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023126/how-can-i-test-https-connections-with-django-as-easily-as-i-can-non-https-connec), I stumbled upon the following bash script.

```
stunnel4 stunnel/dev_https &
python manage.py runserver &
python manage.py runserver 8001
```

What does an and operator do in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ampersand mean at the end of a shell script line?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ampersands put the execution of those commands/processes into the background.  The commands are started and then control immediately returns to the script to execute the next line.  (In other words, the script is not blocked while they run/finish.)

Comment: for the sake of completeness, note that the logical 'and' operator is `&&`.