# Using LetsEncrypt / Certbot with django dev server?

Tags: python, django, ssl, https, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to implement SSL on my dev server, purely just so I can see it working.

I see from the Certbot page that Certbot works with Apache, Nginx, Haproxy and Plesk.

How would I go about implementing this with Django's dev server? I'm not working in a production environment of any kind yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clear something up first: djangos dev server [`./manage.py runserver`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver) does **NOT** serve HTTPS, only plain HTTP.

So you should use a webserver (from the ones you mentioned: Apache, Nginx, Haproxy or Plesk) to test you SSL/HTTPS with the certs.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023126/how-can-i-test-https-connections-with-django-as-easily-as-i-can-non-https-connec) and [this code example](https://gist.github.com/claudiosanches/7012524) for ideas to implement SSL with the dev server.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to confirm your first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a [self signed cert](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/) and then you can [set up Nginx](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) as a front facing webserver for your uWSGI Django app.