# ./manage.py runserver with https

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx

***./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000***

I am using the line above as part of the code I borrowed from github (https://github.com/ribeiroit/boh-puppet) to run bag of holding installation.

So far so good on http but not https. How do I modify the line above to incorporate https? I have already obtained ssl certificate from Comodo and updated my nginx conf.d file but the website won't display in https. Any ideas please shoot my way.

Thank you

Comment: `runserver` is meant for development, you shouldn't use it in production. Nginx + gunicorn is a popular choice.

Comment: If you want your local django development server to handle https, then you will have to install and configure stunnel. For running a local https django server, checkout my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60667888/9384511 . For production, you will need to configure nginx, gunicorn and a process control system like supervisord.

Answer (score 5):

While cezar's recommendation of `django-extensions` is valid to run a server with https, neither `runserver` or `runserver_plus` should ever be used in a production setting.

Quoting [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver):

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

Quoting [django-extensions' documentation](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runserver_plus.html):

> WARNING: This should never be used in any kind of production environment. Not even for a quick problem check. I cannot emphasize this enough. The interactive debugger allows you to evaluate python code right against the server. You’ve been warned.

Now yes, this warning from the `django-extensions` documentation is in reference to a single feature, the interactive console, which will theoretically not be exposed if `DEBUG` is set to `False`. But this is precisely how [Patreon got hacked](https://labs.detectify.com/2015/10/02/how-patreon-got-hacked-publicly-exposed-werkzeug-debugger/), and probably others as well. Why even risk it?

Instead, it would be far better to deploy your application using one of the officially recommended [WSGI servers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/) such as [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) or [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose I use the the third-party app [`django-extensions`](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/), which offers some nice additional functionalities.

One of those extras is [`RunServerPlus`](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runserver_plus.html).

You can then start the server like this:

```
python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file /path/to/your/certificate
```

and open `https://localhost:8000` in your browser.

Comment: Do I have to have 1 line each like this? python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file /path/to/your/certificate.crt ; python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file /path/to/your/certificate.key; python manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: @AdizaBaakoe No, in that case you would try to start the server 3 times. You run just one command: `python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file /path/to/cert 0.0.0.0:8000`. This should be used only for development. In production you use neither `runserver` nor `runserver_plus`.