# Django https with a dev server

Tags: django, ubuntu, https, django-dev-server

I'm trying to use SpeechRecognition/ webkitSpeechRecognition in my website, and thus need to run a dev server in django using https.

I've taken the following steps:

- install and configure `runserver_plus` from `django-extensions`
- add the cert generated by this to my cas in ubuntu.

  ```
  # run server
  python3 manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file certs/localhost --reloader-interval 2 0.0.0.0:8000
  ```

  then

  ```
  # to copy certificates:
  sudo mkdir /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra
  sudo cp certs/localhost.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/localhost.crt
  sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/ 
  sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/localhost.crt 
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
  sudo update-ca-certificates
  ```

  I then restart everything to ensure changes have been accouted for, but the website is still not trusted on `https://127.0.0.1:8000` and `https://localhost:8000`

What am I doing wrong?

Note:

```
awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '
    /BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# gives:
...
subject=CN = localhost
subject=CN = *.localhost/CN=localhost, O = Dummy Certificate
```

This is my chrome certificate invlaid screenshot:

[image: chrome screenshot]

Note II: I am also having the same issue in Firefox

Note III:

I have enabled `Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost.` by copying the below into the browser and selecting enable:

chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

[image]

Comment: try django-sslserver  (https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver)

Comment: I think you did everything right, except you need to tell Chrome to trust your certificate.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate?page=2&tab=Votes)

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks for the response, I have actually enabled this too, I will update the question

Comment: There are more tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate). Problem is, Chrome is constantly changing this so a lot of the solutions are out of date. It's frustrating.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks for the pointer, I'll start trawling the other responses

Comment: If you want to run local django ssl server without using external packages like django_sslserver or  runserver_plus then you will have to install and configure stunnel. Checkout my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60667888/9384511

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a quick fix.  I'll outline the steps here that I took to fix the issue.  For reference, I am using:

- Django 2.2.1
- Ubuntu 18.04.02
- Google Chrome 75.0.3770.142

My solution was heavily influenced by [this article](https://fabianlee.org/2018/02/17/ubuntu-creating-a-trusted-ca-and-san-certificate-using-openssl-on-ubuntu/).

```
# in /System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf
# comment
# RANDFILE      = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

# uncomment
req_extensions = v3_req

# your domain can be whatever for a local dev server, i chose company.dev
[ v3_req ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = company.dev
DNS.2 = *.company.dev

[ v3_ca ]
# update
basicConstraints = critical, CA:TRUE, pathlen:3
# uncomment
keyUsage = critical, cRLSign, keyCertSign
nsCertType = sslCA, emailCA


# in your project root, make a dir for certs:
mkdir certs

# Create CA certificate
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out certs/ca.key.pem 2048

# gen key
openssl req -new -x509 -subj "/CN=companydev" -extensions v3_ca -days 3650 -key certs/ca.key.pem -sha256 -out certs/ca.pem -config /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

# Create Server certificate signed by CA
openssl genrsa -out certs/local.key.pem 2048

openssl req -subj "/CN=local" -extensions v3_req -sha256 -new -key certs/local.key.pem -out certs/local.csr

openssl x509 -req -extensions v3_req -days 3650 -sha256 -in certs/local.csr -CA certs/ca.pem -CAkey certs/ca.key.pem -CAcreateserial -out certs/local.crt -extfile /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

cat certs/local.crt certs/local.key.pem > certs/local-ca-full.pem

# move certificate to ca certs
sudo cp certs/local.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/local.crt
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/ 
sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/local.crt
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates

# update /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost local.company.dev
```

Add certificate to chrome:

- Go to settings
- Search HTTPS/SSL
- Go to Authorities tab
- Import certs/ca.pem

```
# Finally run server with
python3 manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file certs/local.crt --key-file certs/local.key.pem --reloader-interval 2 0.0.0.0:8000
```

open your browser at `https://local.company.dev:8000/` and have a well deserved coffee

If I have missed anything please don't hesitate to comment and I'll update the answer