# Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, https, python-requests

I have a problem with my Django code :

I tried this :

```
requests.post('https://localhost:8000/api/test/', data=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, verify=False)
```

But I got this :

```
{SSLError}HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/test/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

I achieved to solve the problem using HTTP instead of https but I want to use https.

How can I do this knowing that all of this is on the localhost ?

Thank you very much!

EDIT :

Here is the urls.py from the api app :

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token, refresh_jwt_token

from API import views as API views

app_name = 'api'


from API.views import LoginViewCustom

urlpatterns = [
path('test/', apiviews.Test.as_view(), name='test')
]
```

and in the other urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [path('api/', include('api.urls', namespace='api'))]
```

Comment: Please show your **urls.py**

Comment: You must have a certificate to use HTTPS, do you have it?
You can create one for the localhost, see the Let's Encrypt docs: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/.
One more tool, which can help you is the ngrok, you can make a tunnel for the localhost with both HTTP and HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Django's development server, by default run the application over http. Therefore you are getting `Max retries exceeded with url` error as you try to reach it via https.

**Therefore what you actually want is to test/run the local development server with SSL/HTTPS.**

There are several way to achieve this, But what I prefer is to use [RunServerPlus](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runserver_plus.html) from [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). They have [this section](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runserver_plus.html#ssl) for SSL setup.

You can find a good discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8023126/3739532).

Comment: I tried to install RunServerPlus but I got the following error : `"from django.utils.autoreload import get_reloader`
`ImportError: cannot import name 'get_reloader'"`

when I launched the server using this command : 

`./manage.py runserver_plus --cert /tmp/cert`

Comment: Actually, it seems appears that there is no the function `get_reloader()` into the file autoreload

Comment: What version of Django are you using?