# You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP. code 400, message Bad request syntax

Tags: django, http, https, ubuntu-18.04, digital-ocean

I just started learning Django framework, and I tried to deploy my first project on the server from DigitalOcean. If I run

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The server launches. However, once I try to access it from (my-rent-ip):8000 I get this:

```
[25/Aug/2021 01:49:01] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01ü\x03\x03GÛî}Ø²\x921\x0e\x94\x17\x9cÏe¹\x88ñÿÃ\x16\x01éÖRÝ\x00\x95F\x8aG\tÉ 8¯,úÂ\x93´ù\x06Ý\x14¾z\x13Âe4[\x9a,.æ\x96+$<~\x8eq<´\t\x00"ZZ\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03À+À/À,À0Ì©Ì¨À\x13À\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x00')
```

`[25/Aug/2021 01:49:01] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP`

How is this possible if I run production server, not a development one?

I might be doing something wrong with the `setting.py` since it had to be changed a lot for the production purposes. I made a production branch, changed `settings.py` file, and cloned to the server using GitHub. Here it is:

```
from pathlib import Path

from dotenv import load_dotenv   #for python-dotenv method
load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
import os 

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
# DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', '') != 'False'


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    '/var/www/static/',
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You're running your application with `python3 manage.py runserver` which is the **development server**. See: [How to deploy Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/) in the documentation on how you should be setting it up with a production server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server does not support https, so set these settings:

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=False
```

Probably now you need to clear the caches of your browser and restart your server.
The error message refers to the development server because `python3 manage.py runserver` is used only in development.
Note that you should set up https in your production server (when you will have set up https sets again settings that we changed earlier to True) and that setting ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] is a security issue.

Comment: I just tried it. Did not change anything :( Still same issue

Comment: @starship Clear the caches of your browser

Comment: Also tried it. Both google chrome and safari but did not help :(

Comment: In your settings set: `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False`, if not work clear browser cache again and restart the server

Comment: Done this but still same issue :( I deleted cache and history way beyond I started this project

Comment: Actually, I just tried putting http instead of https in front of ip, and it loaded! Thank you so much! Now, I have to figure out how to make Django support https.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use http instead of https in url
```

I had the same problem I was able to access it using http on ec2 ubuntu 20.04

In settings.py use `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*' ,'18.11.22.58']`

Make sure you change ec2 `security group and allow traffic to port 8000`

Run server like this `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Try accesing  your site as `http://18.11.22.58:8000/`  (Not https)

To see how to run on https see here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51384868/3904109

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem I was able to access it using http on ec2 ubuntu 20.04

In settings.py use ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*' ,'18.11.22.58']

Make sure you change ec2 security group and allow traffic to port 8000

Run server like this python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Try accesing your site as http://18.11.22.58:8000/ (Not https)

this worked for me

thank you