# Running Django in IIS

Tags: python, django, iis

I have a Python application that's that has been working correctly as backend for my website, up to now I have been running it using `"python manage.py runserver IP:8000"` in CMD. However I would like it to start using HTTPS, but when I try to access through my browser on `https://IP:PORT` I get the following error:

> You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only
> supports HTTP.

The server I am running all of this is a `Windows Center 2019 DataCenter`, normally on a linux environment I would just use `NGINX+GUNICORN`.

I was browsing possible solutions and stumbled upon [this](https://blog.nonstopio.com/deploy-django-application-on-windows-iis-server-93aee2864c41), however I already am using IIS to host a website (My frontend), so I needed to figure out how to host several websites for the same IP, I have now found [this](https://woshub.com/run-multiple-websites-on-the-same-port-and-ip-address-on-iis/#:%7E:text=To%20open%20this%20site%2C%20just,%2C%20443%2C%20or%20whatever).

Long story short, I configured the new IIS website for it to access my django, I then changed the hostname since both frontend and the new backend will using the same ip and ports (80, 443).

But now I have hit a spot where I'm confused due to my lack of experience in IIS and networking. I can't seem to understand how the request will go through to my Python-Django APP.

**Something important to mention on how I access the Django APP in the past.**
Lets say my front end is https://pr.app.com, whenever any request needed to be made to the backend. I would ask for said information in http://pr.app.com:8000/APIService/..../

This is how the binding for my frontend looks like
[image]

And this is the binding for the new backend where I changed the hostname as the second guide linked said
[image]

Any guidance or help would be most appreciated,
Thanks in advance

***Update**

So I tried pausing my frontend website and used these bindings on the new backend website, I was able to get a screen of Django meaning it seems to be working or at least communicating.

Now I would need to have the hostname of the backend (pr.abcapi.com) somehow refer or redirect to the hostname of the frontend (pr.abc.com).

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Flask based web apps can be hosted via HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ so you can do the same for Django based.

Comment: You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP. For this error you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536491/error-youre-accessing-the-development-server-over-https-but-it-only-supports) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68915954/youre-accessing-the-development-server-over-https-but-it-only-supports-http-c).