# Django+React : CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, header, cors

I am using Django for my backend and React for my Frontend. When I try to send a POST request, I receive :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/package/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I have combined a lot of answers that I found such as [How to use csrf_token in Django RESTful API and React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732815/how-to-use-csrf-token-in-django-restful-api-and-react) and [Django and React: csrf cookie is not being set in request header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72449195/django-and-react-csrf-cookie-is-not-being-set-in-request-header) but still no luck.

1. 'corsheaders' is in my INSTALLED APPS
2. Middleware settings

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

3. CORS settings:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
'http://localhost:3000',
)

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']

from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + ('cache-control',)
```

4. Django view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .forms import PackageForm

from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

class PackageFormView(CreateView):

    form_class = PackageForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'package_form.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

5. React call

```
var csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");

    function getCookie(name) {
      var cookieValue = null;
      if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
          if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === name + "=") {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return cookieValue;
    }

    const cors = {
      "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":
        "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD, authorization",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "withCredentials": "true",
    };

    axios
      .post(
        baseURL,
        {
          title: "title from react",
          description: "description from react",
          "withCredentials": "true",
        },
        {
          headers: cors,
        }
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

I have already spent about 10 hours on this, I still can't find how to fix it.

Comment: If you check your error it says ***`Request header field access-control-allow-methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Header`*** means you're sending invalid `access-control-allow-methods`

Comment: I can see you've passed `authorization` inside `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` which is not a valid [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) method.

Comment: Your **`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`** values shold contain in **`CORS_ALLOW_METHODS`** list if it's not then it will raise above error

Comment: I have aligned the Access-Control-Allow-Methods on both side, but the problem persists

Comment: Did you removed `authorization` from from both side?

Comment: In your frontend JavaScript/React code that’s making the request, completely remove all the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers. Those are all response headers, not request headers. The exact cause of the error message in the question is that your frontend code is sending an `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` request header that it should not be.

Comment: Removing all the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers from your frontend JavaScript/React code will resolve the problem described in the question as currently written. If, after removing those `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers from your frontend JavaScript/React code, you’re then getting another error, then you can then create a separate new question describing whatever the error you’ve run into at that time may be.

Comment: After removing all the Access-Control-Allow-* headers, I am now facing this issue "Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /package/" (from Django) and "POST http://localhost:8000/package/ 403 (Forbidden)" from Chrome

Comment: I think I solved the previous problem. Now I receive: has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response even with changing the CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS to : CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ('content-disposition', 'accept-encoding',                      'content-type', 'accept', 'origin', 'authorization')

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED:

     var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', 'title from react');
    ...

      axios({
        method:'post', 
        url: baseURL,
        headers:{
            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
        } ,
        data: formData,
        xsrfCookieName: csrftoken,
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFTOKEN',
        withCredentials: true,
    })

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ('content-disposition', 'accept-encoding', 'content-type', 'accept', 'origin', 'authorization','x-csrftoken')